# integrating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}(t+2\sqrt{t}x-x^2)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1+(e^{\frac{t}{2}+\sqrt{t}x}-1)q)}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

I need help finding the analytical solution of this integral, if any. Any insights are much appreciated. A lower/upper bound is also good.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}(t+2\sqrt{t}x-x^2)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1+(e^{\frac{t}{2}+\sqrt{t}x}-1)q)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ for $q\in[0,1], t\geq0$.

I know that when $q=1$ or $t=0$ it evaluates to $1$, and to $e^t$ when $q=0$.

For background, this integral is part of a utility function as part of a research I'm doing, where $q$ is the person's belief, and hence a probability between $[0,1]$, $t$ is time and $x$ is the dummy variable of integration. It is derived using the normal distribution hence the exponential and $\sqrt{2\pi}$ terms.

Comment: The only closed forms I can come up with are those corresponding to $t=0$, or $q=0$, or $q=1$.

Comment: Oh yes, I managed to find that it evaluates to $1$ when $t=0$ or $q =1$, and $e^t$ when $q=0$. I'm unable to determine how the integral behaves ourside of the boundaries.

Comment: Is your upper exponent $\frac{1}{2}(t+2x\sqrt{t}-x^2)$ and your lower exponent $\frac{t}{2}+x\sqrt{t}$?

Comment: For positive $t,\  $ does this reduce to $c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-z^2}\left(1-e^{b+z\sqrt{t}}\right)^{-1}dz,\  $ with $b,c$ independent of $z$ but derived from $t$ and $q$?

Comment: Not really because the of the q in the denominator. Doesn't reduce to just $1$